# One-parameter group of unitary operators and Core

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, schrodinger-operators

**Question** : For what condition on $V$ (we can take it smooth, bounded, whatever necessary), the one-parameter unitary group $U(t)$ associated to the seladjoint operator $A=-\Delta+V$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ preserves the space of Schwartz (rapidly decaying) functions.

**EDIT** : the following questions here have been answered negatively:

The following fact is already known :

Let $A$ be a selfadjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$, and let $D$ be a 
dense subset of $H$, that is included in the domain of $A$. We denote $U(t)$ the one-parameter group of unitary operators associated to $A$.
Then :

If $U(t) D \subseteq D$ for all $t$ in an open interval containing $0$, 
then $D$ is a core for $A$. (i.e. $A$ is essentially selfadjoint on $D$).

1) Does the inverse implication hold ? That is : 
if $D$ is a core for $A$, is it true that $U(t)$ preserves $D$ ? (for all $t$ in an interval containing $0$)

2) If the answer is no, my question is then the same but for specific example of $A$ and $H$ : do we have the inverse implication when $H=L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $A$ is a Schrödinger operator $-\Delta+ V$, provided $V$ has "good" properties ?

Comment: I don't see any reason why this would be true; $D=C_0^{\infty}$ is a counterexample to (2).

Comment: Ok, that answers 1 and 2. I edit the question to start with the remaining question.